# How to check is valid token or not. Magento 2 API

Tags: magento2, api, swagger

I need to do API method, which return data from db table just for admin. 
There is my method:

```
/**
     * @return array
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function showAddedSku()
    {
        $insSku = $this->collection->create();
        $data = [];

        foreach ($insSku as $key => $sku)
        {
            $data[$key]['id'] = $sku->getId();
            $data[$key]['sku'] = $sku->getSku();
            $data[$key]['count'] = $sku->getCount();
        }

        return $data;
    }
```

How can I check, that it is admin?

I read, that I must set that:

```
<resources>
    <resource ref="???" />
</resources>
```

but what ref should i choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fill in **self**, **anonymous** or **Magento resource** for this field.

In your case, you should set it as **Magento_Backend::admin**.

Source:

- [Configure services as web APIs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/service-to-web-service.html)
- [Magento 2 tutorial: an overview of the Web API](https://inviqa.com/blog/magento-2-tutorial-overview-web-api)